# Two ng-repeat, $index not sending the right value in the second ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have two ng-repeat that follow each other in the same directive:

```
<section slider class="slider">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="slide in slider[0]" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index)" class="no-text"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="slide in slider[0]" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" class="grid" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index+1)">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" alt="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</section><!-- section.slider -->
```

The first ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index)" is working just fine.
But the second one always sends the last value of the $index (for example, if there is 3 pictures, it will always be 2). 
(The isCurrentSlideIndex($index) works properly.)

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you

**Update:**

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('slider', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.currentIndex = 0;
        $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function(index){
        $scope.currentIndex = index;
        };
        $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function(index){
        return $scope.currentIndex === index;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: why do you add 1 to your $index in the second li ? setCurrentSlideIndex($index+1)

Comment: @AlexChoroshin Because I want the next image to appear! The first ng-repeat is the navigation, and the second is the main slider, when you click on the current image, the next image appear and so on.

Comment: Try adding <p>index=$index</p> after the img tag. btw if the value passed to setCurrentSlideIndex is 2 for 3 images then the value of $index is not the last one.

Comment: @GruffBunny Hi! it's 2 because it starts at 0 :) <p>index={{$index}}</p> I added this, and the right values show up. But the function is still not working...

Comment: Sorry misread the question and thought you said the value passed to setCurrentSlideIndex was always 2. All looks ok to me. Can you show the code for setCurrentSlideIndex?

Comment: @GruffBunny The second one always sends the value 2, and that's not what I want :)
I'm adding the code in my question!

Comment: @Stewie what do you mean? :)

Comment: @loupyestu .@Stewie is talking about a live code demo, via Plunker. [Something like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/lKrSwP?p=preview)

Comment: @loupyestu, I've tried your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRaAL/Rng82/) and it seems to work fine, so probably there is something else in your code that causes this problem. Try to just output `{{$index}}` or `{{slide}}` instead of image, probably the problem is not with them.

Comment: @TylerEich tried it, but couldn't figure it out, sorry.

Comment: @GRaAL I managed to find a solution, it's not optimal but it will do. Thank you.